# Passing state to siblings onChange

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which contains an `<input type="range"></input>` element. In that component I have a function that changes the state when that slider is moved.

I would like to not only be able to use that state to change the `span` tag inside the `Slider` component but also 2 other sibling components which will be rendering that same value.

So as I move that slider I want to see the value change on multiple places on the screen.

**Slider.jsx**

```
function Slider() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0.50)

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className='slider'>
      <div className="label">
        <label htmlFor="value">Value</label>
        <span>{value}</span>
      </div>
      <input onChange={handleChange} type="range" id="value" name="value" min="0.00" max="100.00" step='0.01'></input>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Component1.jsx**

```
function Component1() {

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{value}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Component2.jsx**

```
function Component2() {

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{value}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's the structure of my app, as you can see `Component1` and `Component2` are siblings of `Slider`.

```
├── App.js
├── components
│   ├── Slider.jsx
│   ├── Component1.jsx
│   └── Component2.jsx
```

Comment: Render both component inside `Slider`. In that way it will reflect on all other component

Comment: @ShubhamVerma These components are completely unrelated and on very different places in the DOM. In order to do that my app would have to be one big component calles `Slider`. (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: @nandesuka `useContext` hook is specially designed for this purpose.

Comment: These are not sibling components! They are considered sibling components if they are inside one component rendered with each other. being in the same folder doesn't make them siblings!

Comment: @RadwanAbu-Odeh Right but in my `App.js` they are rendered beside eachother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is React hook that is specifically made for this situation, `useContext`. Look into it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

I also found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc) to be very helpful on this topic.

Comment: Seems to be the right tool for the job! Thank  you so much!!

Comment: `lifting the state up`:  If you have one or two components and you need to share a common state among them then it's time to lift the state up to the parent component. In your case, you need to declare the state inside the App.js which is your parent component and the state will be shared across children. `useContent` hook was designed to solve the problems when we were using the `lifting the state up` concept. I hope this might be helpful. 

Answer (score 1):

You can store value state in a parent component that hosts Slider, Component1, Component2   . For example, I use App Component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0.5);
```

Then, define a function to set value:

```
const onValueChange = (val) => {
    setValue(val);
  };
```

Pass onValueChange to Slider props:

```
<Slider onValueChange={(val) => onValueChange(val)} />
```

Whenever there is a change in slider value, you can invoke:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.onValueChange(event.target.value);
  };
```

Value changed will be reflected in Component 1 and 2:

```
      <Component1 value={value} />
      <Component2 value={value} />
```

See my working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-voice-jjqpw?file=/src/App.js:406-476

Answer (score 1):

Sibling components should be rendered in the same component to be considered siblings.

for example, let's suppose that we have a component called **ParentComponent.js**
I am assuming that **Component2** and **Component1** take property called `value`,
and **Slider** take property called `value` and callback function called `onSlide` which will be called inside **Slider** component whenever the input value changes and passes the value to it.

```js
// ParentComponent.js
import React from "react";
import Component2 from "path/to/Component2";
import Component1 from "path/to/Component1";
import Slider from "path/to/Slider";

export default function ParentComponent(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0.50)

  return (
    <div>
      <Slider value={value} onSlide={(value) => setValue(value)}/>
      <Component1 value={value} />
      <Component2 value={value} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This way your 3 components will be connected with each other within the component
that renders them.